# Find all JIRA issues I've ever commented

Tags: jira

Our company uses JIRA and I'd like to have a way to track all tickets (issues) on which I ever worked. This because after I finish working on a ticket, I reassign it back to the Reporter, and it disappears from "my" tickets.

Using the "Log work" field is not possible.

Therefore, I'd like to create a filter that finds all issues on which I ever added a comment. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer. On the current version of JIRA, use the following JQL:

```
issueFunction in commented("by dr_") ORDER BY createdDate DESC
```

Comment: This requires the Scriptrunner Jira Add-On - it doesn't work on stock Jira.

Answer (score 2):

If you add a comment then this is recorded as a work log (you can see this by using the left hand 'all' options on comments.

So building a JQL filter based on:

```
worklogAuthor= currentUser() ORDER BY updatedDate desc
```

Should find all issues that you've commented on. It may also show you tickets that you've logged work against (eg using Tempo) so it may need refining.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the tab "All" in the issue doesn't show anything related to a work log, and the tab "Work log" shows "No work has yet been logged on this issue", even if I've put several comments in the issue.

Comment: @dr01 Sorry, the comments appear in the 'All' tab on the Activity section - all comments are logged as 'worklogs' which can be queried using the above JQL. Have you tried the JQL?

Comment: Yes, it returns "No issues were found to match your search".

Comment: @dr01 - looks like worklogAuthor is added by Tempo plugin & can be buggy: https://tempoplugin.jira.com/browse/TT-3000?focusedCommentId=54425&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel - I'll see if there is an alternative